# Sequelize: How to soft delete conversation from 1 user but not the other?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

currently in my app user 1 can have a conversation with user 2 and everything is working properly, but when user 1 deletes the conversation from their account it also gets deleted from user 2's account.

How can i delete a conversation from one user and not the other?

I am also using paranoid to keep a record to the conversation in the database.

Here is my conversation model:

```
const Conversation = db.define("Conversation", {},{
paranoid: true, 
timestamps: true, 
deletedAt: "deletedAt",
}
);

module.exports = Conversation;

User.hasMany(Conversation, {
foreignKey: 'user1'
});

User.hasMany(Conversation, {
foreignKey: 'user2'
});

Conversation.belongsTo(User, { as: 'Creator', foreignKey: 'user1', allowNull: false })
Conversation.belongsTo(User, { as: 'Recipient', foreignKey: 'user2', allowNull: false })
```

Here is my delete request:

```
router.delete("/:id", async(req, res) => {  
let { id } = req.params;
await Conversation.findByPk(id).then((conversation) => {
  if (conversation) {
    return conversation.destroy().then(() => {
      res.status(204).send();
    });
  } else {
    res.status(404).send();
  }
});
});
```

In my database, the conversation table has the following columns:

```
id, user1, user2, postId, createdAt,updatedAt,deletedAt
```

thank you in advance for your help, if you require any additional information, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can query a conversation with the option `paranoid: false`. That way you'll get all records including soft-deleted.

It's up to you how to find out to whom to show deleted records and to whom not. I suppose you should store what user deleted a conversion in order not to show him/her conversations deleted by him/her.

Comment: Hi, Anatoly hope everything is good. How do i store that a user deleted a conversation in order not to show it to him/her? Currently when any one of these users deletes a conversation it gets deleted from both.

Comment: Add a link field like `deleted_by_id` and store there a user id who deleted a conversation. Then you can add a condition with this id

Comment: with solution userId will be an array correct, since if both users deleted the conversation it will store the userId of both users. or should i create a new table with columns deleted_by_id and conversationId, since with a new table each deleted user will be stored in separate row?

Comment: So you don't want to show that a conversation is already deleted to a second user at all and he/she can delete it once again?

Comment: Yes, but i think i will have a problem with this approach, what if user 1 deletes conversation then user 2 sends user 1 a message, will a new conversation be created from user 1 and the same conversation be used for user 2?

Comment: Deleted means deleted (cannot be continued). You can show that a conversation is already deleted and ask a user either he/she wish to create a new conversation or create a new one automatically.

Comment: Hi Anatoly, i have a quick question if you do not mind answering, i am currently structuring my query to finAll Conversations and include the messages within is that the correct way of doing it?

Comment: You mean to get a certain conversation along with its messages?

Comment: to get all the conversations the current user has i use findall and include my messages and to get a single conversation along with its messages i use findbyPk

Comment: It's ok, by maybe it would be better not to load messages when you request all conversations because it might be a lot of records?

Comment: i completely understand that is 100% true, but in my All conversations screen in my frontend i am showing the last message being sent by picking it out from all the messages

Comment: In that case it's easier to do `Messages.findAll` and include `Conversation`

Comment: But then how do i show the list of conversation the current user has?

Comment: in my conversations screen, i am showing all the conversations the user has and including the last message sent, but then we i press on a specific conversation i load all messages between the 2 users

Comment: Hmm. Depends on what you try to show: all conversations along with messages or just plain sorted list of all messages with links to their conversations

Comment: Ok, I get it. Then You need Conversation.findAll definitely

Comment: and i include all the messages within Conversation.findAll? is there a way just to extract the last message from the Messages in the backend instead of including all the messages?

Comment: I suppose it cannot be done. Only if you include a link to the last message in Conversation model/table. Otherwise you should request last message for each conversation separately

Comment: I see it's for another question in SO ))

Comment: Do you recommend i include a link to the last message in the conversation table or just include all and pick it out from my frontend? I am currently picking it out from my frontend and it is working.